# EVS and V4L in Android Emulator

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator, android-camera, v4l2

I'd like to use EVS camera system from Android Automotive in Android Emulator.

I've added a camera of my computer to the emulated OS with `hw.camera.back=webcam0` in the emulator's `config.ini` file. Then I've built `sdk_car_x86_64` with `ENABLE_CAMERA_SERVICE`, `Gallery2` package and some camera-related permissions from `frameworks/native/data/etc/`. Now I can open the standard AOSP Camera application, and it works.

Then, I've added few more services: `android.frameworks.automotive.display@1.0-service`, `android.hardware.automotive.evs@1.1-sample`, `android.hardware.camera.provider@2.5-service` and `camera.v4l2` package. With some extra configuration the EvsEnumerator starts and I can run evs_app, but it's empty - it shows black screen and the 'close' button only. Well, it's obvious, because `etc/automotive/evs/evs_configuration_override.xml` points to `/dev/video0` and there is no /dev/video* device in my system - therefore V4L2 returns no devices to EvsDriver (evs-related logs below).

```
2023-10-06 13:49:08.661   250-250   evsmanagerd             pid-250                              I  EVS manager starting
2023-10-06 13:49:08.674   250-250   evsmanagerd             pid-250                              I  Main thread entering thread pool
2023-10-06 13:49:08.674   250-257   evsmanagerd             pid-250                              I  EVS managed service connecting to hardware service at hw/1
2023-10-06 13:49:08.674   250-257   evsmanagerd             pid-250                              I  hardwareServiceName: hw/1
2023-10-06 13:49:14.693   250-257   evsmanagerd             pid-250                              I  EVS managed service is starting as android.hardware.automotive.evs.IEvsEnumerator/default
2023-10-06 13:49:14.696   250-257   evsmanagerd             pid-250                              I  Registration complete


2023-10-06 13:49:08.748   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  EVS Hardware Enumerator service is starting
2023-10-06 13:49:08.750   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  Parsing configuration file takes 9.145000e-01 ms.
2023-10-06 13:49:08.750   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  enumerateCameras: Starting dev/video* enumeration
2023-10-06 13:49:08.750   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  Found 0 qualified video capture devices of 0 checked.
2023-10-06 13:49:08.750   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  enumerateDisplays: Starting display enumeration
2023-10-06 13:49:13.725   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  Display 401cec6a7a2b7b00 is detected on the port, 0
2023-10-06 13:49:13.725   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  Found 1 displays
2023-10-06 13:49:13.726   251-251   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  EVS Hardware Enumerator is ready
2023-10-06 13:49:13.726   251-543   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  Start monitoring new V4L2 devices
2023-10-06 13:49:14.708   251-640   EvsDriver               pid-251                              I  Display resolution is 1024x768


2023-10-06 13:49:08.678   249-249   EvsApp                  pid-249                              I  EVS app starting
2023-10-06 13:49:08.680   249-249   EvsApp                  pid-249                              I  Acquiring EVS Enumerator
2023-10-06 13:49:14.696   249-249   EvsApp                  pid-249                              I  Acquiring EVS Display
2023-10-06 13:49:14.698   249-249   EvsApp                  pid-249                              I  Connecting to Vehicle HAL
2023-10-06 13:49:14.703   249-249   EvsApp                  pid-249                              I  Constructing state controller
2023-10-06 13:49:24.705   249-249   EvsApp                  evs_app                              I  Camera list callback received 0cameras.
2023-10-06 13:49:24.705   249-249   EvsApp                  evs_app                              I  Entering running state
2023-10-06 13:49:24.708   249-784   EvsApp                  evs_app                              I  Activated state 4
```

From static code analysis I found that Camera API (used by Camera applications) uses some EmulatedCameraProvider to access the emulated camera, probably without V4L2.

I don't know, what can I do next. It seems the kernel supports the camera itself (Camera app works) but V4L2 doesn't create /dev/video* representations, and the workaround from Google (EmulatedCameraProvider) applies to Camera API only, not the EVS.

Any help will be appreciated.